# Prolog - Multiplicar los elementos pares de una lista a partir de un número

Tags: lista, prolog, swi-prolog

Estoy programando en Prolog buscando a partir de un número cualquiera dado (F), multiplicar los elementos pares de una lista; conservando aquellos valores que no lo sean, desarrolle lo siguiente y de hecho el programa "compila" sin error alguno pero al ingresar valores solo me devuelve "false", en que podré estar equivocada?:

```
multiplicar(_,[],[]):-!.
multiplicar(F,[X|Xs], [Y|Ys]):- Y is F*X,
X mod 2 =:= 0,
multiplicar(F, Xs, Ys), !.
```

la entrada sería

```
multiplicar(3, [2,3,4,5], N).
```

(En este caso el primer 3 es un número elegido al azar, la salida de dicha entrada debería ser solamente los numeros pares (2 y 4) multiplicados por 3 conservando el resto de los impares por lo tanto la salida sería:

> [6,3,12,5]

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de entrada y salida esperados?

Comment: Claro, la entrada sería multiplicar(3, [2,3,4,5], N). (En este caso el primer 3 es un número elegido al azar, la salida de dicha entrada debería ser solamente los numeros pares (2 y 4) multiplicados por 3 conservando el resto de los impares por lo tanto la salida sería : [6,3,12,5]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando el paso recursivo cuando el número de entrada no es par:

```
multiplicar(_,[],[]):- !.
multiplicar(F,[X|Xs], [Y|Ys]):-
  X mod 2 =:= 0,
  Y is F*X,
  multiplicar(F, Xs, Ys),
  !.
multiplicar(F,[X|Xs], [X|Ys]):-
  X mod 2 =\= 0,
  multiplicar(F, Xs, Ys),
  !.
```

Caso de prueba:

```
?- multiplicar(3, [2,3,4,5], N).
N = [6, 3, 12, 5].
```

Probemos quitar los *cuts* (`!`) del programa:

```
multiplicar(_,[],[]).
multiplicar(F,[X|Xs], [Y|Ys]):-
  X mod 2 =:= 0,
  Y is F*X,
  multiplicar(F, Xs, Ys).
multiplicar(F,[X|Xs], [X|Ys]):-
  X mod 2 =\= 0,
  multiplicar(F, Xs, Ys).
```

Obtenemos el mismo resultado, pero el programa deja una alternativa abierta (que luego no sucede):

```
?- multiplicar(3, [2,3,4,5], N).
N = [6, 3, 12, 5] ;
false.
```

Por lo que podemos reescribir el procedimiento para aprovechar el indexado que hace Prolog, dejando en el primer argumento el parámetro discriminador de cláusulas:

```
multiplicar(F, Xs, Ys):-
  multiplicar1(Xs, F, Ys).  % da vuelta los parámetros, primero queda Xs

multiplicar1([], _, []).
multiplicar1([X|Xs], F, [Y|Ys]):-
  Mod is X mod 2,
  multiplicar2(Mod, F, X, Y), 
  multiplicar1(Xs, F, Ys).

multiplicar2(0, F, X, Y):-
  Y is F*X.
multiplicar2(1, _, X, X).
```

Y ahora sucede deterministicamente:

```
?- multiplicar(3, [2,3,4,5], N).
N = [6, 3, 12, 5].
```